# @Bean method with arguments

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm having some issues setting up a bean with a @Bean annotated method. Spring version is 4.1.4.

The error that is thrown is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'authenticationManagerBuilder' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition
```

At first I thought it was only in my code but then I removed that and started to appear in spring managed beans such as AuthenticationConfiguration.

I'm using the same in other projects and it's working so I believe something is wrong with this configuration.

I found an issue that points to spring version 4.1.3 but it seems it was fixed in the next version so I have no clue on what might be happening.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12488

Again I've been using this kind of strategy for a long time now like:

```
@Bean
public DelegatingTokenGranter delegatingTokenGranter(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    return new DelegatingTokenGranter(endpoints);
}
```

and then calling in the configuration something like:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .addInterceptor(oAuth2ThreadContextInterceptor())
            .tokenGranter(delegatingTokenGranter(endpoints));
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out spring-oauth2 was pulling some modules from spring form the 4.0.8 version. I fixed those and force the current version manually and everything seems to work now.